# VIM: center screen position on current line after jumping to a mark

Tags: vim

How can I map a key to center the screen position after jumping to a mark? Something like:

```
:map M `<wait_key>zz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:map <expr> M printf('`%c zz',getchar())
```