# Automatically center the screen after moving with easymotion

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am using the Vim extension for VSCode.
I like to keep my cursor aligned in the middle of the screen.
It's why i remapped a few keys to perform automatically zz after the commands.
How is it possible with the easymotion feature ? I would like to be directly centered whenever i move to another word.
Thanks !

I tried to browse the internet but found nothing...
I do not want to press zz after each move.

Answer (score 1):

i found solutions for vim, see [Center cursor position after search in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892498/center-cursor-position-after-search-in-vim?rq=3) or [VIM: center screen position on current line after jumping to a mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409774/vim-center-screen-position-on-current-line-after-jumping-to-a-mark). But I can not translate it for vscode vim.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, the answer is related to vscode directly, by setting:
"editor.cursorSurroundingLines": 100,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).